# Python - Deciphering Line from SiriServer Plugin

Tags: python, siri

I'm currently learning how to program plugins for SiriServer, in hope to create a bit of home automation using my phone. I'm trying to figure out how to program the text coverted speech to match and run the plugin.

I've learnt how to to short phrases, like this for example.:

```
@register("en-US", ".*Start.*XBMC.*")
```

Though if I'm understanding it's searching at random for the two words. If I were to say XBMC Start, it would probably work as well, but when I start working with wolframalpha, I need to be a bit more specific.

For example, speech to text saying "What's the weather like in Toronto?", somehow connects to this:

```
@register("en-US", "(what( is|'s) the )?weather( like)? in (?P<location>[\w ]+?)$")
```

What would all the extra symbols in that line mean that could connect these two together? I've tried messing around with a couple ideas but nothing seems to work the way I want it to. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I will break down the example you provided so hopefully that is a good start, but searching for python regex would provide more thorough information.
The parentheses set the enclosed items to be seen as the result, not the individual items by the remaining expression. The pipes mean "or", the question marks mean this portion may or may not be present, and the group for location is a regex which sets the variable "location" as the input provided at this point in the input. The $ at the end means that this will complete the sentence. .* means anything at this place in the input is acceptable, but should also be ignored. Hopefully that helps.